# how change the string in php?

Tags: php

eg:

`$url=http://www.example.com/`.

how to make the $url to this style.

`http://test.google.com/example.com` in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$url_parts=parse_url($url);

echo $url="http://test.google.com/".str_replace('www.','',$url_parts['host']);
```

Comment: Damn, I obviously did too much than needed!

Comment: if the url is http://test.google.com/example.com. can i still get the result as this.http://test.google.com/example.com

Comment: @zhuanzhou:Then you do not need conversion at all. Check host before applying conversation if it is `test.google.com`. you do not need conversion.

Comment: but i must chect it? this is input by the editor. how to check it if has the  test.google.com in the url?

Comment: after applying `parse_url` you can `if ($url_parts['host'] == 'test.google.com')`

Answer (score 3):

[PHP: Simple and easy way to format URL string](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/php-simple-and-easy-way-to-format-url-string/) should clear everything up for you

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "http://www.example.com";

$Step1 = str_replace(array("http://", "https://", "www."), "", $url);
$Step2 = explode("/", $Step1);
$newUrl = "http://test.google.com/".$Step2[0];
```

Basically what I did is replacing any http://, https:// and www. strings from the URL in `$url` and replace them with a blank string. Then I explode the result of this replace on an '/' character, because there might be an URL given as `http://www.test.com/mydir/` so we lose the mydir. If this isn't want you need, skip step 2 and replace $Step2[0] with $Step1 on the last line.

This last line adds the URL you want in `$newUrl`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/";
$url = preg_replace("/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([a-z\d-\.]+)\/.*/", "http://test.google.com/$1", $url);
```

Comment: Please post your answer here, don't just link to some XYZ site

Comment: Sorry, i just new in stackoverflow, and only learn code syntax